# Magento negative inventory

Tags: magento, negative-number

I am using magento 1.7.0.2 for some reason my product quantity field is showing up negative values. I have also checked the backorders it is set to No Backorders.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

have you reindex the data in the index management? after i reindex, my products showing correct stock.

Hope this help